# Upgrade to .Net 8 causes Azure App Service to fail

Tags: .net, serilog

When we upgrade one of our app services from .Net 6 to .Net 8, we get the below error during startup. There should be enough storage on the app service plan, so it cannot be this.
The app service is a 32-bit .Net application. Does anyone have any idea of what could be wrong?
Thanks

> Application: w3wp.exe CoreCLR Version: 8.0.23.53103 .NET Version: 8.0.0 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command. at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateCore(SafeFileHandle fileHandle, String mapName, HandleInheritability inheritability, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileOptions options, Int64 capacity, Int64 fileSize) at
> System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(FileStream fileStream, String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, HandleInheritability inheritability, Boolean leaveOpen) at
> System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile) at
> Serilog.Settings.Configuration.Assemblies.DllScanningAssemblyFinder.g__TryGetAssemblyNameFrom|0_8(String path) at
> Serilog.Settings.Configuration.Assemblies.DllScanningAssemblyFinder.<>c.b__0_5(<>f__AnonymousType2`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier1) at  System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList() at  Serilog.Settings.Configuration.Assemblies.DllScanningAssemblyFinder.FindAssembliesContainingName(String nameToFind) at  Serilog.Settings.Configuration.Assemblies.CompositeAssemblyFinder.FindAssembliesContainingName(String nameToFind) at  Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.LoadConfigurationAssemblies(IConfiguration section, AssemblyFinder assemblyFinder) at  Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader..ctor(IConfiguration configSection, AssemblyFinder assemblyFinder, ConfigurationReaderOptions readerOptions, IConfiguration configuration) at  Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.GetConfigurationReader(IConfiguration configuration, ConfigurationReaderOptions readerOptions, DependencyContext dependencyContext) at  Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, ConfigurationReaderOptions readerOptions) at  BankingCircle.Extensions.Config.Serilog.Config.Builder.Build(IConfiguration configuration, ICorrelationContext correlationContext, String entryAssemblyName) at  BankingCircle.Utilities.ServiceBase.AbstractStartup`1.CommonConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) at
> BankingCircle.Utilities.ServiceBase.AbstractStartup`1.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) at  BankingCircle.Utilities.ServiceBase.ProgramBase`2.ConfigureWebHostBuilderBase(String[] args, TStartup startup, Action`1 configureServices, Action`1 configure) at
> BankingCircle.Utilities.ServiceBase.ProgramBase`2.Run(String[] args, Action`1 configureServices, Action`1 configure) at
> Bankingcircle.NotificationSelfService.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/NotificationSelfService.Api/Program.cs:line 12

Comment: is it ok for you to enable app service auto scale and see if the issue still existed? because according to the error message, it points to the storage space... Or maybe you can [clean the temp files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/493553/how-to-clear-temp-storage-without-restarting-azure) in app service?